# How to add timeout to test when using Google Testing framework

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I'm in need to test C++ code - and I've decided to use Google's testing framework.
I need to make sure that a test doesn't hang due to a new bug.
In the .NET testing framework it's possible to add [Timeout] on to of the test in order to make sure that it does not run for too long.

How can I create a simialr behavior when using Google Test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time out for test cases in googletest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852389/time-out-for-test-cases-in-googletest)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google test does not offer something similar.
http://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=348

You would have to add this functionality in C++

Comment: re "you would have to [implement] this functionality in C++" here is an example implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852389/time-out-for-test-cases-in-googletest (the two questions should probably be merged somehow)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set test properties through cmake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_test/TIMEOUT.html

example:

`set_tests_properties(${Tests} PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 10)`

Comment: Problem with this approach is that within CI, if you rely on getting report files (json or xml) - and using ctest's timeout: no result file is written ..

Answer (score -1):

Building on what @ymochurad said, we ended up using the ctest cli optional argument:

```
ctest --timeout 1
```

to set the a default timeout for all tests. This was sufficient for our needs - hopefully it will help others.

For more info see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html