# Time out for test cases in googletest

Tags: googletest

Is there a way in gtest to have a timeout for inline/test cases or even tests. 
For example I would like to do something like:
          EXPECT_TIMEOUT(5 seconds, myFunction());

I found this issue googletest issues as 'Type:Enhancement' from Dec 09 2010.
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=348

Looks like there is no gtest way from this post. 
I am probably not the first to trying to figure out a way for this.

The only way I can think is to make a child thread run the function, and if it does not return by the 
time limit the parent thread will kill it and show timeout error.

Is there any way where you don't have to use threads?
Or any other ways?

Comment: you might be introducing a [test code smell](http://xunitpatterns.com/Slow%20Tests.html) and making the test brittle. If you really want to do it, you can write your own assertion macro

Comment: for the assertion macro, we probably need two threads running?
The child thread runs the function, and if it doesnot return by time limit, the main thread just stops and returns false or something.

Comment: The discussion seems to lead into an implementation discussion. Since there are many ifs and whens, I'd suggest to discuss the details in the googletest or any other testing framework issues. The scope is too broad. Yes, spawning child threads might help, but it's hard to say, whether it'll be robust. You might also wait for the call to end and use a stopwatch to assert the time

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov : waiting for the call to end in my case won't work.  I am testing an implementation that uses regular expressions, and I want to make sure it doesn't invoke catastrophic backtracking if the match fails.  A correct implementation should take much less than 100ms; catastrophic backtracking could take 10**30 seconds.

Comment: @MartinBonner As, I guess, your algorithm doesn't have cancellation points (as it should run really fast), you'll probably need to terminate the whole process if "catastrophic backtracking" happens. This means, each of such test cases should run as a separate process. There are multiple ways how that could be implemented, e.g. with a custom test harness, but the discussion would be too much for SO. How about starting a github project with travis-ci integration to play around with ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I just came across this situation.

I wanted to add a failing test for my reactor. The reactor never finishes. (it has to fail first). But I don't want the test to run forever.

I followed your link but still not joy there. So I decided to use some of the C++14 features and it makes it relatively simple.

But I implemented the timeout like this:

```
TEST(Init, run)
{
    // Step 1 Set up my code to run.
    ThorsAnvil::Async::Reactor                      reactor;
    std::unique_ptr<ThorsAnvil::Async::Handler>     handler(new TestHandler("test/data/input"));
    ThorsAnvil::Async::HandlerId                    id = reactor.registerHandler(std::move(handler));

    // Step 2
    // Run the code async.
    auto asyncFuture = std::async(
        std::launch::async, [&reactor]() {
                               reactor.run();   // The TestHandler
                                                // should call reactor.shutDown()
                                                // when it is finished.
                                                // if it does not then 
                                                // the test failed.
                            });

    // Step 3
    // DO your timeout test.
    EXPECT_TRUE(asyncFuture.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000)) != std::future_status::timeout);

    // Step 4
    // Clean up your resources.
    reactor.shutDown();             // this will allow run() to exit.
                                    // and the thread to die.
}
```

Now that I have my failing test I can write the code that fixes the test.

Comment: Alternatively if you want to do something similar without C++ 11 or 14... there might be a way to do something similar with `boost::asio::io_service`.