# How to use Googletest to test a function that leads to an infinite loop

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse-cdt, googletest

Is there any way to use googletest to test a function that will lead to an infinite loop? I have the following code where the assert functionality is defined:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define ukd_assert(expr) \
    ((void)((expr) ? 0 : (Assert::failedAssert(), 0)))
#else   // NDEBUG
#define INSTANTIATE_ASSERT(fp)
#define ukd_assert(expr) ((void)0)
#endif 

    volatile bool loopFlag = true;
    void failedAssert( void )
    {

        const char *str = "Assert failed\r\n";

        // now hang
        while(loopFlag)
        {}
    }
```

I need googletest to run a test to check that the failedAssert function is called from the assert definition. I am using a windows 10 computer if that matters.

Comment: Start the function in a separate thread and have a timeout?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to set this up? I am pretty new to googletest and coding in general.

Comment: So a program which has an infinite loop within it is ill-defined in `C++14`.  This means that this mechanism may not work in the future.

The usage of a infinite loop, can cause issues with a running CPU, as the CPU has to stay working, and it limits the operating system's opportunity to do a good job with other things on the computer.  (Consider a sleep, or an exit(); ).  You shouldn't use volatile to communicate between threads.  Use std::atomic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time out for test cases in googletest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852389/time-out-for-test-cases-in-googletest)

Comment: @mksteve no, it's not, there's even an attribute to mark that explicitly as an intended behaviour https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn. Especially on embedded targets `main()` function usually never ends (or one of the main loop functions called from `main()`).